# react-navigation/native presentation modal not show popup in react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have code to show cart in e-commerce app.

Structure like that:
RestaurantScreen has basketIcon, and when onPress in basketIcon, it will show  BasketScreen.
I want to show it with popup, and i have this code in App.js.

```js
<Stack.Screen
   name="Basket"
   component={BasketScreen}
   options={{presentation: "modal", headerShown: false}}
/>
```

But when click showCart, it only view with page display (not popup). So how can I fix it?

I also add in 3 file js above, with version of react-navigation/native.

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
```

```json
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
```

Comment: It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485996/10856571

Comment: i have just add group for stack, but it's not work like my required